# Listbox breaks when setting it to a virtual instance from a class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a weird problem that I can't wrap my head around.

I have the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public WithEvents MyClass1 As New MyClass

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyClass_UpdateListbox() Handles MyClass1.UpdateListbox
        For Each sItem as String In MyClass1.Listbox
            MsgBox(sItem)                        'an MsgBox shows correct items each time.
        Next sItem
        Me.Listbox = Me.MyClass1.Listbox         'doesn't work and breaks listbox.
        Me.Listbox.Items.Clear()                 'listbox is empty anyway, but has no effect.
        Me.Listbox.Items.Add("event triggered")  'does nothing.
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClass
    Public Listbox as new Listbox
    Public Event UpdateListbox()

    Public Sub New()
        'Constructor. sub.
        Me.AddItem("Populating listbox")
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddItem(sItem as String)
        Me.Listbox.Items.Add(sItem)
        RaiseEvent UpdateListbox()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I comment the following lines in above code, the listbox keeps adding `event triggered`, as expected. Of course, I don't have to remove the clear one. It will work, but then it just adds the same item. If I use a command button and call MyClass.AddItem("Something") that is correctly added too as long as the below is commented out. But if not, then once the listbox is in broken state, nothing can be added anymore.

```
Me.Listbox = Me.MyClass1.Listbox      'doesn't work and breaks listbox.
Me.Listbox.Items.Clear()              'listbox is empty anyway, but has no effect.
```

How can I use a virtual listbox and assign it to my real listbox?

Also, instead of assigning one listbox to the other, I can of course use that for each loop and add each item one by one which works, but that for each look was for debugging purpose in the first place.

EDIT:
My goal with this application is to build a Todo list with features that are not in a todolist. This is a project I build for work because there I need a tool like this. I already have a todolist that I use but I built it wrong in the past. Everything was condensed in form1, no modules no extra classes. As a result I got weird bugs that I patched with workarounds. I am now rebuilding the application from the ground up, separating tasks in its own classes so I can apply business logic and have a true OOP application. The todo list will become its own class, and managing the list etc will be handeled by this class. It interacts with controls on the form, such as buttons and listboxes. If I just use form1.listbox from the class, things break at program start. I started another question and the below code was a now deleted answer. At first I did not get it working because I did not realize the listbox crashes if I assign it the virtual instance.

So my goal is to have the todolist be handled entirely by the todolist class. It does need a way to interact with controls on form1, and that is the puzzle I'm currently trying to solve.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You apparently have a ListBox Control on a Form (which is of course linked to its base ListControl which is linkd to a Win32 ListBox Control), then you assign its instance to another ListBox (which is not *virtual*, it's a different Control with its own Handle) and you expect that the graphic representation of the previous instance of the ListBox to update when you add items to the other ListBox? Of course it won't happen, you're interacting with a different Control.

Comment: BTW, `Me.Listbox.Items.Add()` cannot raise the `UpdateListbox` event, since its the `AddItem()` method of  `MyClass` that does that -- You see the LIstBox clear its Items when you call `Clear()` because the handle of the owner of the ObjectCollection (the Items) has not been updated yet, it will be after you exit `MyClass_UpdateListbox()`. Try to call `Clear()` only after, see what happens (or doesn't happen).

Comment: If you want to *link* an existing ListBox Control to your `MyClass` object, pass the instance of the ListBox to the class Constructor and assign it to a Field, then you can *manipulate* the ListBox (and its *visual content*) from `MyClass`. -- BTW2, `MyClass` is not a good name for a class in VB.Net, you should use another name, even as an *example*, it may confuse someone.

Comment: @Jimi The MyClass was just chosen as example. Its not in my project. As for the other comments, I have a hard time understanding what you're saying. I'm not that good with vb.net unfortunately.

Comment: It's not about the language, it's about Reference Types. -- You have a ListBox Control on a Form: the Reference to this Control is store in `Me.ListBox`. You then create a new ListBox in `MyClass`: this is another *real* Control, with its own Handle. Its Reference is assigned to the `Public Listbox as new Listbox` Field in `MyClass`. When you do this: `Me.Listbox = Me.MyClass1.Listbox`, you assign the Reference of the ListBox object created in `MyClass` to the `Me.Listbox` Field. Now both Fields point to the same ListBox object, the one you created in `MyClass`.

Comment: As per your previous question and 100% understand not an answer but still wondering exactly what the goal of this pattern your implementing is.  Perhaps you could expand on your question with some context because how this stands to me right now looks like a horrible spiders web of un-necessary complexity that will become a maintenance nightmare

Comment: @Jimi I see.. Could you post an answer with a sample code on how I would be able to pass the reference of the form1 object to the MyClass and use that instead of creating a new instance there? I previously used form1.listbox from MyClass in a different question and was shot down for it not being the way. If you do, I gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @Jimi thinking even more about it, am I correct to say that if at project launch, I call the following: `MyClass.Listbox = me.Listbox` I can then correctly make changes to the form1 listbox, because I first set the class's listbox reference to the form1 one? Or is that bad practice also?

Comment: The correct-ish way is to add a constructor to your class, e.g., `public sub New(lb as ListBox) me.listBox = lb end sub` and initialize the class with `[Some Field] = new MyClass(me.ListBox1)`. Now the Field in MyClass holds a Reference to the ListBox Control shown in the Form. The access modifier of the ListBox must remain `Private` or `Friend`, never `Public` (real *bad practice*). You still have a problem: the MyClass object must be declared in the Form itself >> You could add a Public Property or Method in the Form that returns the ListBox instance and declare the `MyClass` object [...]

Comment: at the Application Scope (in the `MyApplication` Class, add, e.g., `Public listBoxHandler As MyClass`), override `OnStartup` and add `listBoxHandler = New MyClass([App NameSpace].[Some Form].[Property or method that returns a ListBox instance]`). Now you can use the `AddItem()` method in MyClass to add items to the *live* ListBox in `[Some Form]`. The `listBoxHandler` object is accessible anywhere in the Application, so you can manipulate the content of the ListBox from anywhere.

Comment: @Jimi it would really help if you can post an answer with an example code. The code in the comments is not readable enough that I can wrap my head around it.

Comment: Final note and explanation of `correct-ish`: what you're trying to do is to decouple the View from the Business Logic. This is a common problem that has been addressed in different ways implementing different Patterns: MVC, MVP, MVU (Elm), MVVM, ReactiveUI etc.. You should really look into these existing Patterns before anything else (especially MVP and [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI), the latter is part of the .Net Foundation). -- Yes, there's a learning curve, but probably worth your while.

Comment: If you want an example of the *simplified* method previously described, no problem, I can post it but keep in mind it's a **very** *thin layer*, you'll find out soon enough.

Comment: Yes please. I currently have something that works (I create the object at form1_load) and from there tie the control to the class, but its not "standard" and if I can learn a better way, that would benefit us all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code, the main problem is that the Field that hold the instance of a Control shown if a Form is reassigned to the instance of another ListBox Control defined in a custom class:

```
Me.Listbox = Me.MyClass1.Listbox
```

From now on, `Me.Listbox` points another ListBox that is not show on screen, so any attempt to update the Form's child ListBox fails, except when Me.Listbox.Items.Clear() is called - in the same procedure - after it's being reassigned, because the handle of the Owner of the [ObjectCollection](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/ListBox.ObjectCollection.cs,20) (the object that holds the Items shown in the ListBox) has not been updated yet. It's going to fail after the current method exits nonetheless.

---

As noted in comments, this is a simplified method to handle a Form and its child Controls using a handler class. The *contract* between the class handler and a Form is *sealed* by an Interface (named `IFormHandler` here).
A Form that implements this Interface exposes the methods defined by the Interface that allow to trigger Actions and specific behaviors, depending on the Type of Control and the implementation.

I suggest to take a look at the `MVP` or [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) (MVVM-derived) for WinForms Patterns.

---

**How too proceed**:

Open up the `ApplicationEvents` class object.
If you don't have it already, select `Project -> Properties -> Application` and click the `View Application Events` button. It will generate `ApplicationEvents.vb`. Find it in Solution Explorer and open it up.

It should look like this (plus a bunch of comments that explain what it's for):

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Paste into `MyApplication` these lines of code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Public SomeFormHandler As MyFormHandler(Of SomeForm)

        Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) As Boolean
            SomeFormHandler = New MyFormHandler(Of SomeForm)
            Return MyBase.OnStartup(e)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Add an Interface that defines the Actions (or Behaviors) that a Form must implement.
Here, the `GetUsersList()` method specifies that a Form that implements this Interface must return the instance of a child ListBox Control.
(To add an Interface, select `Project -> Add -> New Item...` and select the `Interface` template. Name the file `IFormHandler`)

Extend this Interface as needed, to add more Methods or Properties that define actions and behaviors.

```
Public Interface IFormHandler
    Function GetUsersList() As ListBox
End Interface
```

A Form that implements the `IFormHandler` Interface implements and exposes the `GetUsersList()` method, which returns the instance of a ListBox Control (named  `usersList` here)

There's nothing else to do with this Form, the control is handed over to the `MyFormHandler` object that is initialized with this Type.

```
Public Class SomeForm
    Implements IFormHandler

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetUsersList() As ListBox Implements IFormHandler.GetUsersList
        Return Me.usersList
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, to show `SomeForm`, you can use the `MyFormHandler` class object show below.

```
' Set the Owner if called from another Form
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.Show(Me) 
' Or without an Owner
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.Show()
```

To close `SomeForm`, you can either use its handler:

```
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.Close()
```

or close it as usual:

```
[SomeForm Instance].Close()
```

If `MyFormHandler` determines that the instance of `SomeForm` has been disposed, it creates a new one when you call its `Show()` method again later.

To update the ListBox Control of `SomeForm`, use the public methods exposed by the `MyFormHandler` class:

```
' Add a new element
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.UpdateUsersList(UpdateType.AddElement, "Some Item")

' Remove an element
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.UpdateUsersList(UpdateType.RemoveElement, "Some Item")

' Replace an element
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.UpdateUsersList(UpdateType.ReplaceElement, "New Item", "Some Item")

' Clears the ListBox  
My.Application.SomeFormHandler.ClearUsersList()
```

All these actions generate an event that you can subscribe to when needed.
See also the example that shows how to raise a custom event when the ListBox raises one of its stardard events; `SelectedIndexChanged` is handled here.
See the implementation of `MyFormHandler`.

**Generic Form handler:**
A Form needs to implement the `IFormHandler` Interface for the `MyFormHandler` class to accept it as valid.
You can of course extend the Interface, to add more Actions, or build a `MyFormHandler` class object that uses a different Interface, or more than one.

```
Public Class MyFormHandler(Of TForm As {Form, IFormHandler, New})
    Implements IDisposable

    Private formObject As TForm
    Private IsInstanceSelfClosing As Boolean = False
    Public Event UsersListUpdate(item As Object, changeType As UpdateType)
    Public Event UsersListIndexChanged(index As Integer)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeInstance()
        Dim lstBox = formObject.GetUsersList()
        AddHandler lstBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf OnUsersListIndexChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeInstance()
        formObject = New TForm()
        AddHandler formObject.FormClosing, AddressOf OnFormClosing
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnFormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        IsInstanceSelfClosing = True
        Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateUsersList(updateMode As UpdateType, newItem As Object, Optional oldItem As Object = Nothing)
        If newItem Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("New Item is null")

        Dim lstBox = formObject.GetUsersList()
        Select Case updateMode
            Case UpdateType.AddElement
                lstBox.Items.Add(newItem)
            Case UpdateType.RemoveElement
                lstBox.Items.Remove(newItem)
            Case UpdateType.ReplaceElement
                If oldItem Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("Replacement Item is null")
                Dim index = lstBox.Items.IndexOf(oldItem)
                lstBox.Items.Remove(oldItem)
                lstBox.Items.Insert(index, newItem)
            Case Else : Return
        End Select
        RaiseEvent UsersListUpdate(newItem, updateMode)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearUsersList()
        formObject.GetUsersList().Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnUsersListIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent UsersListIndexChanged(DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedIndex)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Show(Optional owner As IWin32Window = Nothing)
        If formObject Is Nothing OrElse formObject.IsDisposed Then InitializeInstance()
        If formObject.Visible Then
            formObject.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            formObject.BringToFront()
        Else
            formObject.Show(owner)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        If formObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Not formObject.IsDisposed) Then
            RemoveHandler formObject.FormClosing, AddressOf OnFormClosing
            IsInstanceSelfClosing = False
            Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If formObject Is Nothing OrElse formObject.IsDisposed Then Return
            Dim lstBox = formObject.GetUsersList()
            RemoveHandler lstBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf OnUsersListIndexChanged
            RemoveHandler formObject.FormClosing, AddressOf OnFormClosing
            If Not IsInstanceSelfClosing Then formObject.Close()
            IsInstanceSelfClosing = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Enumerator used in `MyFormHandler`:**

```
Public Enum UpdateType
    AddElement
    RemoveElement
    ReplaceElement
End Enum
```